# Access Report based on questions answered

Tags: ms-access, report

I have reports generated by queries. I have some people who are not Access savvy (at all). Can I create a report that when opened, asks a couple questions, then generates the report based on how the person answered? I have very very limited VBA skills (but willing to learn).  If I can keep them from opening Queries, it may be easier for them to get the information correct.

For example.  I have a report that provides all the open records for all our sales people. Rather than create 10 different reports (one for each sales person, and 1 that is shows everyone), can I have the report generated based on if the person who opens the reports wants to see all open records for all sales people or just those from one sales person?  I have something similar for suppliers - which suppliers have open records (if I only want to a report for a specific supplier, versus all suppliers).

Thanks!
-Cheryl

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is for programming questions which have specific details, instead of open ended recommendations.

Comment: How much more specific do i need to get to have the question answered?

Comment: Well even slightly specific would help. This question is really asking "How do I use Access to prompt users to run a query" which really isn't specific at all.

Comment: How are they running the reports right now? Choosing them from the navigation pane? You might want to take a look at using forms to enter criteria and open your report. You could also use parameters. What have you tried?

Comment: I have not tried the form.  Normally I update the query, then send out the reports. However, I want to be able to go on vacation.  The other queries I have parameters, and was thinking of just using parameters to have the necessary questions answered.  I like the idea of using forms to enter criteria and open the report. (Pretty new to the Access database thing, so I modify queries, reports, forms as I learn new information)

Comment: +1 for "I want to be able to go on vacation." :) -- Using parameter queries for the end users kind of works, but is klunky and error-prone. Using forms and a bit of VBA is a much better way.

Comment: Thanks Andre - I will work on creating a form that will generate the report and the necessary VBA to get it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment about using parameters and personally running each needed report, a form is a much better option. Apart from allowing data validation, you can also use lookups to ensure the values being passed to the data source are legitimate.

Your form should have controls for each criteria field you plan to use to generate your report. To reference the form controls in your query, use this nomenclature:

`[Forms]![NameOfYourForm]![NameOfYourControl]`

Using the form reference will eliminate the need to build multiple iterations of the reports and queries. Keep in mind which criteria you may want to omit though, for example, a combobox of suppliers if NULL could return ALL suppliers, so your query would need to accommodate that.

Comment: Thank you very  much.  I am looking forward to giving this suggestion a try.  Thanks to everyone!